# Dyadics (binary basis)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can anyone tell me why, for every $s\in [0,1]$, there exists $(\varepsilon_j)_j$ such that $\varepsilon_j\in \{0,1\}$ and
$$s=\sum_j^{\infty}\frac{\varepsilon_j}{2^j}.$$

Comment: Do you understand why every real number in $[0,1]$ can be represented by an ordinary decimal expansion?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Given $s\in[0,1]$, we can define the numbers $\epsilon_j$ recursively.

Let $a_0=0$. Given $a_j$ for some $j\ge 0$, let

$$\epsilon_{j+1}=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }s-a_j<\frac1{2^{j+1}}\\
1,&\text{if }s-a_j\ge\frac1{2^{j+1}}\,,
\end{cases}$$

and let $a_{j+1}=a_j+\epsilon_{j+1}$.

- Verify that $\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\epsilon_j}{2^j}=a_n$ for each $n\ge 1$.

Thus, we need to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=s$.

- Show that if $s=1$, then $\epsilon_j=1$ for each $j\in\Bbb Z^+$, and verify that in this case $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=s$.
- What is $\sum\limits_{j=n+1}^\infty\frac1{2^j}$? Use this result to show that if $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, and $\epsilon_j=1$ for all $j>n$, then $\epsilon_n=1$.
- Conclude that if $s<1$, then $\{j\in\Bbb Z^+:\epsilon_j=0\}$ is infinite.
- Show that if $\epsilon_j=0$, then $s-a_j<\frac1{2^j}$.
- Conclude that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=s$, i.e., that $s=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty\frac{\epsilon_j}{2^j}$.